# Multidex in an Android library project?

Tags: android, android-library, android-multidex

Is it possible to use Multidex inside a library project? It's not so hard to hit the 65k limit when you have libraries like Dagger, RxJava and Databinding. I'm really stuck here, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the official documentation?. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html. This should give you a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to 100% validate that this is true but based on how the normal build process works my hypothesis is that because your AAR consists of `.class` files and the normal android build process includes dexing all project files including libraries (AARs, and JARs) that adding multidex to your library really will just help with making sure that when they library is built in its root project that it is able to multi-dex properly.

Let's say you you build an AAR (which needs Multi-Dex) and then you import that aar into another project. Chances are you are going to need multi-dex on the project consuming the library as well because though the compiler doesn't need to compile the java classes it will still need to dex and do resource compilation on the entirety of the AAR.